# Trying to implement drag and drop files feature in listwidget from QtDesigner

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qt-designer

I have setup a GUI in QtDesigner, which is its own python file that I am importing at the top of my code (from QtDesignerGUI). I have a push button that will open a File Dialog box. I then want the user to have the ability to drag files from the file dialog into the list view to be stored/read. Below is my code. I'm able to get the FileDialog box to open but cannot get the drag and drop to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Below is the code

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import Utilities
import functools
from QtDesignerGUI import *

class DesignerGUI(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Report_Output()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.connect(self.ui.SelectFile, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.select_file)
        self.connect(self.ui.listView, QtCore.SIGNAL("selected"), self.dropEvent)

    def select_file(self):
        fileName = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self,"Select Files","Directory","file type")

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls:
            event.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)
            event.accept()
            links = []
            for url in event.mimeData().urls():
                links.append(str(url.toLocalFile()))
            self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("dropped"), links)
        else:
            event.ignore()
```

I am having trouble with the self.connect function as well. I'm not 100% sure how it all works and believe that is part of the reason the dropevent is not working. My Listview object that I want the files to appear on is named "listView"

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc of the dialog box from Qtdesigner?

Comment: Qt4 is end-of-life since Jan. 2016; Qt LTS 4.8 came out 2011. It's about time…

Comment: Besides the fact that Qt4 is now deprecated, you should *not* use a QFileDialog static for drag&drop operations.